# How can I use Haskell exception for index negative

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve one of my Haskell question. The question asks me to that extracts a slice of a list of integers. Function should take a list and two indexes new list number contains between two indexes.

For this function;

- First index should smaller than second index
- First index cannot be negative number

  - we cannot use any built-in functions

example:

```
makeSlice [1,2,3,4,5] 2 3
[3,4]
makeSlice [1,2,3,4,5] (-1) 3
*** Exception: First index cannot be negative
```

I tried a few option but below function if I give positive number I am getting **"First index cannot be negative"** exception

```
makeSlice :: [a] -> Int -> Int -> [a]
makeSlice [] _ _ =[]

makeSlice (h:t) i k

    |k < 0 = []
    | i>k  = error "First index cannot be greater than second index (i > k)"
    | i< 0 = error "First index cannot be negative (i < 0)!"
    | i>0 = makeSlice t (i - 1) (k - 1)
    | otherwise = h:makeSlice t (i -1 ) (k - 1)
```

Can you help me to find where I am making wrong?

Comment: I guess your problem might be in lack of terminating term for recursion. You subtract one from i on each call but recursion ends only in error.

Comment: If you make it to the `otherwise` case, then you know `i< 0` is `False` and `i>0` is `False`. Now think about what this implies about the value of `(i -1 )`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Hey @DanielWagner I guess same that @GrayCat mentioned. This is the recursion part I guess so when not i > 0 I should get exception but I could not get it. Also did you say if you use "otherwise" case when i < 0 `False` then i > 0 `False`?

Comment: @macintosh You check *both* that `i< 0` and `i>0` before hitting the `otherwise` case. So if you hit the `otherwise` case, both of those must be `False`.

Comment: I got it, so only when `i > 0` should `i - 0` otherwise should on `i`

Answer (score 1):

Add terminating condition for your recursion. On each call you subtract one from i and when it reaches below 0 you just throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest approach to this uses the Prelude [take](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.13/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#v:take) and [drop](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.13/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#v:drop) functions to process the list.  Then you just need to do the bounds checking:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> Either String [a]
slice from to lst
  | from < 0 = Left "First index cannot be negative (i < 0)!"
  | to < from = Left "First index cannot be greater than second index (i > k)"
  | otherwise = Right $ take (to - from) $ drop from $ lst
```

Here I'm using `Either` to report either success or failure.  On the one hand that disagrees with the problem as stated; on the other, it gives callers a chance to handle the error without immediately terminating the program, which is more polite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I forgot to add but I cannot use any built-in function. I guess take and drop functions are already built in.